# using a common layout for several modules in Yii

Tags: layout, module, yii

I am using Yii framework in my web project. now, I have several modules and I want to use only one layout for all modules. I have used following codes for determining the layout for every controller/action in each module:

```
$this->layoutPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.views.layouts');
$this->layout = '//layouts/myLayout';
```

Is there any other solution to do this by using same code in init() function of each module?
in other word, I have to write the above 2-line code in each action and i think it's not good and i want to reduce my number of lines of codes. for example as follows:

```
class StaffModule extends CWebModule
{
    public $layout;
    public $layoutPath;
    public function init()
    {
        $this->layoutPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.views.layouts');
                $this->layout = '//layouts/myLayout';
        $this->setImport(array(
            'staff.models.*',
            'staff.components.*',
        ));
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. Help me please.

Answer (score 2):

Just use

> $this->layout='//layouts/myLayout';

without

> $this->layoutPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.views.layouts');

because // mean you specific absolute path from root

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are having in init function is in the right direction..I think the problem could be.. as you are defining `layoutPath` you shouldn't have `//layouts..`

```
$this->layoutPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.views.layouts');
$this->layout = 'myLayout';
```

and you don't need these:

```
public $layout;
public $layoutPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered similar question on

[using common layout for several modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877387/yii-module-layout?answertab=active#tab-top)

The solution is set the layout on beforeControllerAction in your module. 
It should work.